# Making colours of a colour ramp noisy

Tags: texturing, materials, objects

I have a nice gradient texture going on for a project I am working on. The nodes in order with their outputs are as follows:

Texture Coordinate: Generated
Mapping: Vector
Gradient Texture(Linear): Color
Invert(Fac: 0.75): Color
Math(Add)(Value 2: -0.29): Value
ColorRamp(Green at 0.005, Black at 0.007): Color
HSV: Color
Then principled and output.

I want the colours in the colorramp to be noisy, add a bumpy effect. I tried to create this with a bump node but no texture fit what I was looking for. I can't see how I can make the colours a little noisy without affecting the gradient. It's like the noise texture needs to be in the colorramp.

Comment: Why don't you just mix in a *[Noise Texture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohGDY.jpg)*?  -- or additionally, a *[Musgrave Texture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngk08.jpg)* for some "pebbles"?

Comment: i know you are new here, but pls just make a screenshot of your nodetree and paste it in here. Nobody want to read the textual desription of a node tree....thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In this example, I used a Noise texture to affect both the colors and the surface normals. Both can be used to make a "bumpy" effect. Let me know if you have any questions on how to modify it if needed.

[image: Bumpy]